# Can't authenticate a cURL request despite supplying username and password

Tags: php, apache, http, curl

I have a dev URL that is behind HTTP authentication using a simple .htpasswd file - nothing special about that at all, all standard.

I am trying to hit a URL on that domain via cURL but am getting this message of course:

```
Unauthorized
This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server
```

I have added what I believe to be the correct parameter to authorise the url but with no joy. Just the same message. I have echo'd out the username and password and these are exactly as I would enter into the browser prompt.

[image]

What is the next step to debug this?

Comment: It would be far more constructive to output *text* code rather than image code.

Comment: and `echo $result;die;` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by NOT using curl_setopt_array, instead setting each 3 separately. Cannot currently explain why this is different but it works! :(

[image]